# Set a check box with specific name as well as id as checked using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML file, I want to set a check box with specific name as well as id as= `checked`. How can I acheive this..?

eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myName_1" id="1" value="my Value 1"> my Value 1
```

I know `document.getElementById('id').checked = true;`, but this only checks `id`. I need to check for `id` and `name` simultaneously using `JavaScript`. Pls help.

**Edit:**
More specific:

```
 if(document.getElementById(1) && document.getElementById(1).type == "checkbox" ){
     document.getElementById(1).checked = true;
 }
```

**Note:** I have other elements that have same id, but different name, as well as same name, but different id. But no two have both in common.

Comment: IDs are always unique in the DOM so you shouldn't check on id AND name

Comment: Alternatively you could have a look at function `getElementsByName`

Comment: @Bartdude jap, that would work [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LW7Qn/) :)

Comment: @nkmol: I got a DOM with different elements(type of) having same id. Is it is not valid? So what I've to do?

Comment: @Bartdude: I have  several fields with same name :(

Comment: @Thampuran i've added an answer :)

Comment: Same-ID is **never** okay. You still unfortunately see it in some validation frameworks that (incorrectly) believe it was the only way to do what they wanted. Same-name can be valid, for instance if there are multiple forms, or a series of radio buttons/check boxes all apply to the same 'key' with different values. My personal preference is for using *just* the name property to access things in javascript.

Comment: #id's are suppose to have one unique presence so you can't have two id's that have the value 1 for example. I would say to expand on question and explain why you are trying to set the input as checked and the reason why you need to target both the name and id. Give more of an idea of what your program or app is trying to accomplish I think it would lead to better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as i said IDs are always unique in the DOM. So having elements with the same ID is **not valid**.

You can however select by the name attribute with `getElementsByName` as this selection supports *multiple element*. It will just create a array that you can acces through the index value. So you can just loop through all the element and check them one by one:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByName('myName_1');

for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
   elem[i].checked = true;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LW7Qn/2/)

Comment: thanks nkmol, I managed to do the rest with the help of you code. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, not ideal, but would solve the problem.

```
var names = document.getElementsByName(nameToFind);
names.forEach(funciton(item) {
  if (item.id == idToFind)
    item.checked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Having id of HTML elements, starting with a number is incorrect. Rename your id and make it unique. Also value of id of 1 evaluates to true by javascript engine.
However if your HTML document is HTML5 compliant then id starting with a number is not problem.

Comment: HTML5, element ID's can start with a number.

Comment: User did not specified the doctype, so assuming is NOT HTML5

Comment: I agree that a user should avoid this. But this is still no answer to his question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by several comments, it is not valid to have more than one element with the same id. If there are more than one of the same id, the behavior is unreliable.
If you have groupings of elements that are similar, a common convention with many developers is to **give them a common class**. This could/would replace your use of name. You can then search on elements within a certain class that have a specific id. (Which may be redundant, depending on your use.)

Searching by class is done with `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")`, which returns an array of elements, similar to `getElementsByName`. Once you have this array, you can then loop through to determine if your id is within that class group[see note below] and apply effects as necessary. (e.g. `elementArray[i].checked = true`)

Note - It would be much more efficient to search for the id then determine the class, in my opinion.